# What is the probability that the number of times prime number appears is more than number of times even number appears , when a dice is rolled 6 times

Tags: probability

Answer is $\dfrac{98}{243}$ but help me how to get this. The dice is rolled 6 times and you have to calculate the probability that:
[no. of times prime appears] > [no. of times even appears]

Comment: Hi welcome to MSE, It would be interesting to see what you have tried? Also,  there is a problem in the question, you are asking something that has a true or false answer. And you are saying that the answer is a number, which is contradictory.

Comment: @SagarM: The question is clear to me (although amWhy's edit made it a little less clear): you have to calculate the probability that no. of primes > no. of even numbers.

Comment: Aah! @TonyK, thanks for clarifying